# What is a numerically stable way to generate an exponential distribution that properly yields very large, low-probability values in Excel and C++?

Tags: distributions, excel, numerics, c++

I have sets of sampled data with the following statistics:

[image]

Because the mean is so close to the min, and because of our understanding of the process that generated the samples, we are treating the samples as exponentially distributed, with lambda = 1/average.

I am trying to generate random samples with as similar as possible a distribution as the measured data for use in our simulator, which is in C++. When I mock this up in Excel I find that the max of a batch of samples is never anywhere close to the max of the measured samples.

After having read "The Black Swan", by Nasim Taleb, I really don't want to model my process in a way that ignores black swan / long tail events.

In Excel I'm using the following math to generate a sample:
=-LN(1-RAND())*SAMPLE_MEAN+SAMPLE_MIN
as inspired by this page: https://www.ntrand.com/exponential-distribution Note that multiplying by SAMPLE_MEAN is the same is dividing by lambda.

The problem is that the max of my synthetic samples is always around 25,000 for a batch of 10,000 samples. Indeed, if I replace RAND() with 0.999999999999999 the generated samples is 85,914.4. This is true for any number of 9's more than about 7. I assume Excel is using double precision floating point and just runs out of precision.

I noticed that since 1-RAND() will have the same distribution as RAND() I removed the "1-". This helped somewhat. Now if I replace the RAND() with 0.000000000001 I do get bigger numbers. After a while it uses exponential notation and I can store up to 1E-307, which yields a sample value of 1,758,388, which is the magnitude I'm looking for.

However, in practice RAND() doesn't seem to yield numbers that small. In a spreadsheet with 16 million cells calling RAND(), across many attempts the smallest number I've gotten is 0.00000006103030236737080, yielding an exponential sample of 41,577.7. This is way more trials than the actual sample count of the real process that yielded max values of 1-2 million.

So is there a more numerically stable way of generating random numbers with an exponential distribution so that I can properly get samples in the millions in Excel and in C++?

Comment: `1-RAND()` definitely does not have the same distribution as `RAND()`!  Floating point arithmetic does not follow the usual mathematical laws.  However, your basis for supposing your data might follow an exponential distribution is weak: how have you tested that supposition?

Comment: You seem to have pretty compelling evidence against the distribution being exponential with the sample mean giving the distribution parameter. If you want to generate larger “black swan” values, that seems reasonable, but the evidence points toward an exponential distribution not being the tool for the task.

Comment: Can you show us (include in the post by editing) some plots of the data, for instance aqqplot against the exponential?

Comment: *"properly yields very large, low-probability values"* what does this mean? Every potential outcome has a low (almost zero) probability. Or does it mean that you want a large range with extremely large values included as well? What would be the motivation for this?

Comment: Probably more technical than you want, but you can find a formula for the moments of the *order statistics* of an exponential distribution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80475/order-statistics-of-i-i-d-exponentially-distributed-sample), i.e., you can find the theoretical expectation (mean) and variance of the *maximum* of a sample of 10,000 exponentially distributed values ...

Comment: @whuber, fine, but since the equation we're implementing treats RAND() as a uniformly distributed on [0,1] it's fine to do the same with 1-RAND(). That isn't the core of the issue.

Comment: Everyone seems to be focusing on the motivation to my question. That might end up bearing fruit, and thoughtful comments can be appreciated. But I'm also interested in my actual question. Does anyone have anything to say about a more robust method of generating random numbers with an exponential distribution?

Comment: To the two people who fairly question whether my distribution really is exponential, no, I can't provide a plot of the data, unfortunately. Can I ask what other distribution this might be whose PDF is asymmetric, has most of the weight far to the left and has a really long tail?

Comment: Re "it's fine to do the same:" not so.  The logarithms of `RAND()` can become *much* more extreme than the logarithms of `1-RAND()` (depending on the specifics of Excel's implementation, which has changed over time).  But that's not the underlying issue.  Of greater concern is the likelihood that your exponential model is a poor one for the data.

Comment: The math that yielded the equation with the RAND() assumes that RAND() is uniformly distributed over [0,1]. It makes no assumptions about, and has no dependencies on, the logarithms or other numerical properties of RAND(). Yes, the results will be different, but numerics just don't exist in the context of the pure math, where I did that transformation, so it's hard to buy that something that's correct in the pure math is wrong numerically, in a context where the numerics are unknown and can change at any time. But do you have any suggestions of other models of the data I should consider?

Answer (score 3):

If it helps, this is what I get in R when simulating 1 million draws from an exponential distribution with lambda 1/15000 and 1/300 (your scenarios C and D more or less):

```
summary(rexp(n = 1000000, rate = 1/300))
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
   0.001   86.221  207.984  299.828  415.304 4348.287 

summary(rexp(n = 1000000, rate = 1/15000))
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
     0.01   4299.59  10364.26  14971.25  20741.95 211248.84
```

You can see that the min and max are too low compared to yours. So, as others have pointed out, it seems that the exponential distribution is not a good fit for your data and the numerical stability is not an issue. Or maybe those min and max values are unreliable datapoints.

Comment: Thanks for testing this. But it seems that your conclusion assumes that R's numerical stability is perfect, but instead it could simply be matching that of Excel.